# Transfer file from local machine to remote windows server using python

Tags: python, windows, server

How can I easily copy a local file to a remote server using python?

I don't want to map the drive to my local machine and the windows server requires a username and password.

The local machine is also a windows machine.

Examples I've seen are with linux and mapping the drive. Unfortunately that's not an option for me.

Comment: How could you copy the file *by hand*? Is there a network access to the remote server (`\\server\share\path\to\folder`), or do you use a file copy program (filezilla, scp, sftp, ftp, etc.)? You will have to mimic or use the same from Python.

Comment: I want have a network access to the remote server(ie \server\path\to\folder). Adrian Logut suggested that I implement powershell with python to get the job done

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subprocess` module or `os.system` to launch a command into a windows shell. Then you can use Powershell or cmd instructions.

Comment: I found some examples that I'll try out tomorrow when I get to work. Thank you for the input